# create new column dynamically

Tags: ssis

How will I create a new/virtual column after pulling data from source before putting into the destination ? which task should I use for creating a new/virtual column ?In my case, I want to create a column of datatype datetime and fill data on that field based on a condition. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [derived column transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Derived Column Transformation will give you the flexibility of the dynamic column creating and split condition is also will give you the derived column and condition checking together with same features.

It depends on your business logic and performance view to pick up the approach.

thanks

prav